# how can i use position-fixed with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

this is a simple code with two divs, when i add position-fixed class to first div , the second element  will move under the first element, how can I fix this problem.

```
 <div class="d-flex">
  <div class="bg-warning position-fixed">first element</div>
  <div class="bg-primary ">second element</div>
</div>
```

i need to position fixed the first element ,but the second element will move